# If statement for Nested List

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to use `If` function over a nested list below, to generate a new list that any element greater than 1 will be set to 0. 
Example list:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {-0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 2}, {2, 3, 0.3}}
```

Result:

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {-0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.3}}
```

I thought this was simple, but I tried sth like `fun[x_]:= If[x<1,x,0]` and mapping it to the list, it turns out it cannot work on a nested list. Sorry if the question was asked, try to find a solution but failed!

Answer (score 6):

```
lstlst = {{1, 2, 3}, {-0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 2}, {2, 3, 0.3}}
lstlst /. {x_ /; x >= 1 -> 0}
```

or, if you really prefer to use `Map` with `If`, set the levelspec:

```
Map[If[# >= 1, 0, #] &, lstlst, {2}]
```

Comment: Thank u very much!

Answer (score 5):

```
lst = {{1, 2, 3}, {-0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 2}, {2, 3, 0.3}}; 

lst (1 - UnitStep[lst - 1])
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {-0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.3}}

Alternatively, you can also `Map` your `fun` at `Level` `{-1}`:

```
fun[x_] := If[x < 1, x, 0]

Map[fun, lst, {-1}]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {-0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.3}}

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip):

```
list = {{1,2,3}, {-0.1,0.5,0.9,1.1,2}, {2,3,0.3}};
Clip[
    list,
    {Min[list], 1-$MachineEpsilon},
    {0,0}
]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {-0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.3}}

**Update**

Since there is a fair number of answers now, we can compare. Here is a dataset:

```
data = RandomReal[2, {10^5,10}];
```

Here are the various answers:

```
f1[data_] := data /. x_ /; x>=1 -> 0 (* Alan *)
f2[data_] := Map[If[# >= 1, 0, #]&, data, {2}] (* Alan *)
f3[data_] := Apply[Function[x, If[x<1, x, 0], Listable][{##}]&, data, -1] (* user42582 *)
f4[data_] := data (1 - UnitStep[data - 1]) (* kglr *)
f5[data_] := Map[If[# < 1, #, 0]&, data, {-1}] (* kglr *)
f6[data_] := Clip[data, {Min[data], 1-$MachineEpsilon}, {0, 0}] (* Carl *)
```

Here is the comparison:

```
r1 = f1[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = f2[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r3 = f3[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r4 = f4[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r5 = f5[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r6 = f6[data]; //RepeatedTiming

N @ r1 === N @ r2 === N @ r3 === N @ r4 === N @ r5 === N @ r6
```

> {0.84, Null}
>
> {0.9662, Null}
>
> {1.42, Null}
>
> {0.00706, Null}
>
> {0.96, Null}
>
> {0.0037, Null}
>
> True

Summarizing, my answer is the fastest with @kglr's a close second. The others are about the same.

Comment: Another variation using Clip: `Clip[list, {-Infinity, 1}] //. {1 -> 0}`

Answer (score 2):

One other solution to the problem is to use

```
sel = Function[x, If[x < 1, x, 0], Listable]
```

The function `sel` performs the comparison that is discussed in the body of the question (see Question) and returns the argument it is passed (ie `x`) when that is less than unity (and zero otherwise).

It also carries the `Listable` attribute ie it is automatically threaded over lists eg `sel[{1,2,3}]` returns `{0,0,0}` as expected. This behavior would not have been possible without `Listable`.

Now, applying the `sel` function on the input (ragged) list will produce the requested result. Please verify that evaluating

```
Apply[sel[{##}] &, lst, -1] == res
```

returns `True`, where `lst={{1, 2, 3}, {-0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 2}, {2, 3, 0.3}}` is the input list and `res={{0, 0, 0}, {-0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.3}}` is the desired output.